# Modelling alternatives and performance when traversing a tree structure in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, tree-traversal, data-modeling

I modelled a tree structure using the Neo4J graph database. All nodes represent a category with a characterising name. So I have to traverse my tree very often from the root to a specific node / category. To which node depends on a list coming as input. This list contains strings representing the names of the categories from the root to the target node.

I wonder, if it would be effective to store these names as the types of the edges instead of a name property in the particular nodes. 
I thought that when I do so, Neo4J doesn't have to look for the fitting name property of every child node every time going a step deeper in the tree. Instead Neo4J could lookup the name in the map that contains the outgoing edges.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds sensible. How many different names do you have? If it is just categories those shouldn't be millions.

Did you load your data into the graph and run a performance comparison between both approaches? Is it a performance critical thing in your graph?